# How to delete commits from gitlab? (Git-revert not working)

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-commit, git-revert

I am trying to delete some gitlab commits that were made in error.

the answers provided in other threads were

1. click on commit name
2. click "options"
3. click "revert"

When I attempted to delete the commits, they were not deleted. Instead, two extra merges were created on top. I'm sure this is normal, but I don't understand why it has done that, and more importantly, it hasn't deleted the commits.

How can I delete the commits completely so that the last available commit is the one with the superman logo? thanks

Comment: Did you expect the revert operation to delete the commits? Because it's *not* what it's supposed to do. The principle is actually to create new commits to negate the effects of the given "bad" commits". You might have misunderstood the principles behind revert/reset.

Comment: Is there a way to simply delete them?

Comment: Try reset and force push. I don't know if there is some way to do this from gitlab web UI.

Comment: @NickyLarson It depends on whether the branch is shared or not. If it *is*, do **not** go for the reset/force-push. If you're alone working on it, that's the way to go.

Comment: By "shared", @RomainValeri means this: Are more people than just you working on this branch? Since we can see at least two names attached to commits there, the answer might be "yes", in which case it *might* not be as easy as a simple reset.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Good catch :-) Didn't see the author names here but yes, that's exactly what I meant, thanks Lasse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The non destructive way is simply to do what you've done: revert your commits. Sure there "2 more commits", but **your branch is in the same state than before**.

The destructive way is to delete commits but this would override your branch history. Because of this you'll need extra rights to rewrite the branch history.

> Before to go further, you need to understand that:
>
> - Depending on the repository configuration you may NOT be allowed to do such a thing
> - You'll force everybody else working on this repository to force pull the branch, therefore they may loose their work if they're not well understanding the process
> - You'll loose EVERY commit after the superman one, even those that would have been created by someone else in the last hours
>
> **I highly recommend you to NOT do this.**

By code, assuming this is the branch `master`:

```sh
# Retrieve the latest version
git pull origin master
# Goes back to the superman commit
git reset --hard 329a7a0e
# Force push to rewrite history
# Will be refused if the branch is protected
git push origin master --force
```

With Gitlab, I think you have no other way than:

- Create a new branch from the `329a7a0e` commit, named `master-rollback`
- Delete the `master` branch
- Create a new branch `master` from `master-rollback`
- Delete the `master-rollback` branch

Comment: Note that in gitlab the default-flag of the master still has to be changed to master-rollback branch. This is done under: Settings -> Repository -> Default branch